# How to cache last loaded data on the client in Cordova app?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm building an app on Meteor and have been testing my app on my Android device. It works great. I'm publishing my data on the server and subscribing to it in the client.

But when I don't have data or the server is down, the mobile app shows no content. This makes sense as it can't load anything. But it must be possible to cache the last loaded data from the server so there is at least something to display in the mobile app when there is no connection.

I looked into appcache but that seems to be for assets as opposed to database content. Does anybody know how to make the Cordova version of a Meteor app cache the database locally so it will also work offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cache our iPad application configuration we use localStorage. It's super easy to use and really worked out well for use.

```
localStorage.settings = settings; // data from server
```

and when the application starts:

```
var settings = null;
if( navigator.network.connection.type === Connection.NONE ) {
   settings = localStorage.settings
} else {
   // fetch settings from server
}
```

We've been running this implementation for over a year now without any issues.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm gonna accept this answer because it made me Google localStorage solutions for Meteor and I stumbled upon ground:db. https://atmospherejs.com/ground/db It's a package that does what you describe just by "grounding" a Meteor collection.

Just one line made it work, which was this line:
Ground.Collection(<collectionVar>, '<collectionName>');